# Broadcast Receiver life cycle

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

BroadcastReceiver is registered inside manifest file. What happens when the app is not running and broadcast is received?

Does Android create a new process to handle that broadcast?

Does only the class which extends BroadcastReceiver is created?

How does the whole process work?

Comment: "Does Android create a new process to handle that broadcast?" -- yes. "Does only the class which extends BroadcastReceiver is created?" -- the `Application` singleton, and any `ContentProvider` implementations that you have, should also get created.

Comment: So, I assume it's not a good idea to use a static variable inside the receiver class.

Comment: What happens when we use alarms with the broadcast receiver? Does the exact same process happen when the receiver receives an alarm and application process is not running? (assuming that application is not killed by user himself by force stopping but OS).

Comment: Yes. An `AlarmManager` alarm triggering a broadcast via a `PendingIntent` is no different than anything else triggering a broadcast, with respect to the need for a process.

Comment: And what about using a static variable inside the receiver class

Comment: That will live as long as the process does. Once `onReceive()` returns, the process might be terminated within milliseconds, if nothing else is causing Android to keep the process around. Use `static` fields for a cache or other similar transient data.

Comment: U told me that the Android will create a new process to handle broadcasts that happen when application process is not running. If I am using a static field inside onReceive method which is devlared in MainActivity class. Will that work??

Comment: And what's the chance of android killing a process that has a BroadcastReceiver attached to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Android create a new process to handle that broadcast?

Yes, if the app is not running and the event you have registered for happens, the Android OS handles that situation by creating a new process. If you register it in code, it's tied to the life of the activity/service you registered it in.

> Does only the class which extends BroadcastReceiver is created?

The Application singleton and any ContentProvider implementations that you have should also get created.

**Thank you, CommonsWare for your help.**